# Объединение временных периодов по состоянию (T-SQL, MS SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеем оборудование, которое каждую минуту пишет в базу (MS SQL Server) своё состояние (1-под нагрузкой, 0-без нагрузки)

Необходимо объединить периоды с началом и окончанием каждого состояния

Исходная таблица:

```
StartTime           EndTime             Value
2023-09-17 05:41:00 2023-09-17 05:42:00 1
2023-09-17 05:42:00 2023-09-17 05:43:00 1
2023-09-17 05:43:00 2023-09-17 05:44:00 0
2023-09-17 05:44:00 2023-09-17 05:45:00 0
2023-09-17 05:45:00 2023-09-17 05:46:00 0
2023-09-17 05:46:00 2023-09-17 05:47:00 1
2023-09-17 05:47:00 2023-09-17 05:48:00 1
2023-09-17 05:48:00 2023-09-17 05:49:00 1
2023-09-17 05:49:00 2023-09-17 05:50:00 0
2023-09-17 05:50:00 2023-09-17 05:51:00 0
2023-09-17 05:51:00 2023-09-17 05:52:00 0
2023-09-17 05:52:00 2023-09-17 05:53:00 0
2023-09-17 05:53:00 2023-09-17 05:54:00 0
2023-09-17 05:54:00 2023-09-17 05:55:00 1
2023-09-17 05:55:00 2023-09-17 05:56:00 1
2023-09-17 05:56:00 2023-09-17 05:57:00 1
2023-09-17 05:57:00 2023-09-17 05:58:00 1
2023-09-17 05:58:00 2023-09-17 05:59:00 0
2023-09-17 05:59:00 2023-09-17 06:00:00 1
2023-09-17 06:00:00 2023-09-17 06:01:00 1
2023-09-17 06:01:00 2023-09-17 06:02:00 1
2023-09-17 06:02:00 2023-09-17 06:03:00 1
2023-09-17 06:03:00 2023-09-17 06:04:00 0
2023-09-17 06:04:00 2023-09-17 06:05:00 0
2023-09-17 06:05:00 2023-09-17 06:06:00 0
2023-09-17 06:06:00 2023-09-17 06:07:00 1
2023-09-17 06:07:00 2023-09-17 06:08:00 1
2023-09-17 06:08:00 2023-09-17 06:09:00 1
```

При группировке по Value получаю следующий результат:

```
SELECT [StartTime]=MIN(StartTime), [EndTime]=MAX(EndTime), [Value]
FROM BD
GROUP BY [Value]
ORDER BY [StartTime]

StartTime           EndTime             Value
2023-09-17 05:41:00 2023-09-17 06:09:00 1
2023-09-17 05:43:00 2023-09-17 06:06:00 0
```

**А результат нужен такой:**

```
StartTime           EndTime             Value
2023-09-17 05:41:00 2023-09-17 05:43:00 1
2023-09-17 05:43:00 2023-09-17 05:47:00 0
2023-09-17 05:47:00 2023-09-17 05:49:00 1
2023-09-17 05:49:00 2023-09-17 05:54:00 0
2023-09-17 05:54:00 2023-09-17 05:58:00 1
2023-09-17 05:58:00 2023-09-17 05:59:00 0
2023-09-17 05:59:00 2023-09-17 06:03:00 1
2023-09-17 06:03:00 2023-09-17 06:06:00 0
2023-09-17 06:06:00 2023-09-17 06:09:00 1
```

Подскажите пожалуйста какую функцию T-SQL использовать для получения нужного результата

Comment: в желаемом результате строки ``2023-09-17 05:43:00 2023-09-17 05:47:00 0`` и 
``2023-09-17 05:47:00 2023-09-17 05:49:00 1`` - не понятны. возможно, вместо 47 должно быть 46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схематично:

```
WITH
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY starttime) lagvalue
    FROM table
    ),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN value = lagvalue
                       THEN 0
                       ELSE 1 
                       END) OVER (ORDER BY starttime) groupnum
    FROM cte1
    )
SELECT MIN(starttime), MAX(endtime), value
FROM cte2
GROUP BY value, groupnum;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!